# Фиксированный столбец табличной верстки

Tags: html, прокрутка, css

Вечер добрый, господа и дамы.

На неком сайте висит таблица режима работы и стоимости. Моя задача - сделать так, чтобы в мобильном варианте таблица отображалась с горизонтальной прокруткой, при этом, левый столбец никуда не уплывал, а фиксировался на месте.

Нашла хитрое решение через создание дополнительного блока и наложения его на левую часть таблицы, где должно быть фиксированное меню, но что-то мне кажется это подозрительным и дай, думаю, спрошу у вас, возможно, кто такое уже делал и скажет иной выход (плагин, скрипт какой, или может я что-то в css упустила).

Скажу сразу, таблица имеет такой тип

```
<tbody>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
```

Кто что скажет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужна такая разметка:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
...
```

И стили:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 100px; /* Сдвинет всю таблицу внутри на 100 пикселей */
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
th {
    background-color: #0074d9;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; /* Прижмет к левому краю .outer, который на 100 пикселей шире .inner */
    width: 100px; /* Занимаем отведенное место */
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/y4w6fbon/)**

*p.s. `<tbody>` должен быть внутри `<table>`, а не снаружи.*

Comment: Эх. Я почти так и думала, но, конечно, до такой продуманности действий мне было далеко. Спасибо огромное!